# Variable is used before being assigned when creating a helper class

Tags: typescript, axios, nuxt.js

I have a backend that returns a json response like this:
[image]

But when i use axios in my vue nuxt project I get the json response from axios. Which is something like axios: { status, data ... }.

I did not know axios did this, but I would like to keep my backend response. So I made a helper file that just returns axios.data. I also assign few common things so I don't have to declare them everytime.[image]

My service file that has all my requests:

```
const getAllJobs = () => request({ url: url.default, method: 'GET', });
```

And my vue file where i use the const:

```
getAllJobs().then((res: any) => console.log(res));
```

I don't really understand why it says variable is used before being assigned. i tried this but that also did not work: `let response: AxiosResponse | null = null;` this gives the error that it is null.

Comment: I understand the error, but not what you're trying to do with this code.  `response` never gets a value, so what is the point of returning `response.data`?  Where are you setting `response` to the actual response?  (nowhere)

Comment: Hi, uhm so I first had this `const getAllJobs = (axios: any) => axios.get(url.default);` amd that worked, but now that i removed the error with @Stéphane Veyret  helpi get undefined, so you are right. I am trying to recreate the axios.get, but i don't realy know if i am doing it the correct way. Figuring things out :(

Comment: Ok I get it.  You need to actually execute the request!  I'll post a solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Wow! that would be really helpful and appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

You are trying to access a property of the `response`, but the response doesn't actually exist because you never set it anywhere.  You can suppress the error by messing with the types, but this function is pointless if you don't actually set the response.  You need to call upon `axios.get` or `axios.request` (which can handle 'GET' and 'POST') in order to actually get the response.

### The Basic Solution

```
import axios, {AxiosRequestConfig} from "axios";

const request = async (options: AxiosRequestConfig) => {

  if (! options.headers) options.headers = {}; // not actually necessary

  const response = await axios.request(options); // has type AxiosResponse<any>
  
  return response.data; // has type any
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN4EEXoBKApgI4CuxaMAwhAHYBmwA5gL5yNQQhwBEyVGj4BuAFBiAxg2pwoZSrIC8iNAE96kuAAoIYGKnpoAXHHxCSFKrQbMWASjhKAfDglw4wRjoCEcPQYyAHQAFsQIACbEUGiOAYZooeFRMU44bOJiHtJG8PJokEbEaQgA7gjA8ILoQfJW1Lr6CfYicAD0bXAhCGhwMGpgxeZEVIVoxAA8CPRqzllw8-Iw5FD0cqMyxEERCDAIrR1dPX0DxdNqYmwSObIsxDC4ADaPAFIQAEa9KtqOLuv1MG02DgK0epgA5CA1NQoMB6CxwVgQPcQhAIhCAOIAUQAKoi4GwWhI7g9nm9Pj8gjAwvRtNp8qZzr9XDcII8to8ICx6VR7C0gA)

Here we use `axios.request` to fetch the data based on the `options`.  Since that is an `async` function, we need to `await` its response and our `request` function needs to be `async`.  You can read up on async/await, which is the more modern syntax for dealing with promises.  But you can still use `.then()` in your vue file because an async function is essentially a promise behind the scenes.

### The Advanced Solution

From the typescript perspective, there are a few improvements which can be made to our `request` function.  `url` is actually an optional property on the interface `AxiosRequestConfig`, but we probably want to require it.  So you can use `(options: AxiosRequestConfig & {url: string})`.  You could require other properties as well.

The returned type of `request` is `any` because axios doesn't know what type of data it is going to be fetching.  If you do know, you can use a typescript generic to specify the returned data type.  Otherwise, if you have `data: any` from a response, you can write `data as MyType` to assert the type of `data`.

```
const request = async <T>(options: AxiosRequestConfig & {url: string}): Promise<T> => {

  const response = await axios.request<T>(options); // has type AxiosResponse<T>
  
  return response.data; // has type T
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAQwB7AgZwDRwN4EEXoBKApgI4CuxaMAwhAHYBmwA5gL5yNQQhwBEyVGj4BuAFBiAxg2pwoZSrIC8iNAE96kuAB4AKhgB8ACghgYqemgBccfEJIUqtBsxZwAZDnJQANjepQwPTsAJQ2AArcIMBoxHoGcEoJ2BJwcNKW8PJokJbEiYgA7gjA8ILoAHTyjtTxJmYWaCEicAD0rXAAFghocDBqYPl2RFS5sfFiaZNyxDDe9DM5MsQVACYIMAgt7V09fQP5umJsEkEwxFCMCJL5AFIQAEY40+YwPsT+MIHB4mloCD4EFA1DZ6OQQA8LuITlIZPAWLNcD4fPcHr0VEYQokEtVFDBtKiANoAXWM2Dg3j8cAA5GgeE5vixqVgQLNOhBVjZqQBxACiumZcDYzQkCJgSJRjzQmIqME6xHoRiMACspW0AFS7Xr9QZwInEuDq1pYpJwVVoiogBBgIxmx7Yu0PCr-QHArHNIA)

For example, if you know that `getAllJobs` returns an array of an interface `Job`, you can call `request<Job[]>(..)` and the returned type will be `Job[]`.

```
interface Job {
  title: string;
  salary: number;
}

const getAllJobs = () => request<Job[]>({ url: 'somestring', method: 'GET', });

getAllJobs().then((jobs /* has type Job[] */) => jobs.map( job => job.salary) );
```

So it's ok to do something like the above, where we map the jobs to their salaries.

Comment: Wow! this is exactly what I was looking for actually. I can't leave you a like yet (low reputation) but you have my like! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to assign the variable… For example:

```js
let response = {} as AxiosResponse;
```